# Low confidences with DBpedia Spotlight

Tags: annotations, dbpedia, spotlight-dbpedia

I am a little bit confused why I get such low confidences with the REST API of Spotlight.

I run the following code/call:

```
curl http://spotlight.dbpedia.org/rest/annotate \
 --data-urlencode "text=Hallo, i am looking for a new Microsoft or Apple tablet." \
 --data "confidence=0.2" \
 --data "support=20"
```

then I just get similarityScores between 0.130 and 0.135.

When I try this text in the demo (http://dbpedia-spotlight.github.io/demo/) then I can get the results until to a confidence of 0.60.
What cause my low confidence values? How can I obtain correct values?

p.s. Is there anywhere a more comprehensive documentation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First `similarityScores` does not correspond to the values of `Confidence`.
But more importantly http://spotlight.dbpedia.org/rest/annotate is not the endpoint being used by the demo.

The endpoint being used by the demo is: http://spotlight.sztaki.hu:2222/rest

Comment: thanks for sharing this information. Is their some more documentation available to get an understanding how the level of Confidence is calculated in spotlight, especially in the direction of disambiguation?

Comment: Probably this mail will help you clear it out: http://sourceforge.net/p/dbp-spotlight/mailman/dbp-spotlight-users/?page=2